# JQuery : link title attribute unchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm new with JQuery, and have problem with this

```
$("#trigger").click(
  function(){
        $("#pnel-menu").toggle("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        $(this).attr("title", "Open Panel");
  }, function() {
            $(this).attr("title", "Close Panel");
            return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="pnel-menu">
  menu
</div>
<p class="slidebar">
  <a id="trigger" title="" href="#"></a>
</p>
<div id="pnel-cont">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
</div>
```

what i like to do is to change the .trigger title dinamically when it clik to open or close the #pnel-menu.

But it wont change? does anybody can give some clue, thanks before :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  $("#pnel-menu").toggle("slow");
  that.toggleClass("active");
  that.attr("title", (that.hasClass("active")?"Close":"Open") + " Panel");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should use two functions with `,` as a delimiter

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
       $("#pnel-menu").toggle("slow");
       $(this).toggleClass("active");
       if($(this).attr("title") == "Open Panel"){
              $(this).attr("title", "Close Panel");      
              return false;
       }
       else
              $(this).attr("title", "Open Panel");
       });
```

Hope this works ^^